# How should I fix TypeError "property 'props' of undefined"?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

When I click on the button [Add to Cart] I'm getting an error:
[image].
How should I fix that?
Here's my [full code link](https://gist.github.com/Y-Taras/be0777006e925a9d80e367221a481caf), and below is an abstract, that is relevant to question:

```
class ProductsList extends Component {
  ....
  renderProductsList() {
    function mapProductCards(elem) {
      return (
        <Card className="m-1" style={{width: '18rem'}} key={elem.id}>
            .... 
            <CardText>isAvailable</CardText>
            <Button onClick={() => this.props.addItemToCart(elem.id)}>Add to Cart</Button>
          </CardBlock>
        </Card>
      )
    }
....
this.props.products ....
        .map(mapProductCards)
....
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
....
  addItemToCart(value) {
    dispatch(addToCart(value));
  } 
....
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProductsList);
....
```

Comment: try to store this to that ( that= this)  , and use that in map function ( that.props...map() ).

Comment: `renderProductsList` is a functional component?

Comment: no it's a function. I'll add a link to full code in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the start of your renderProductsList function, assign your `this` variable to a local one. Like this:

```
renderProductsList() {
  var that = this;
  function mapProductCards(elem) {
    return (
```

and then just use `that` where needed. For example, your button would now be:

```
<Button onClick={() => that.props.addItemToCart(elem.id)}>Add to Cart</Button>
```

---

Alternatively, use an arrow function instead. Like this:

```
renderProductsList() {
  mapProductCards = (elem) => {
    return (
```

this will preserve the reference of `this` to the object you actually need.

---

**EDIT**

After looking at your full code, based on how you use your `mapProductCards` function, you need to pass in the correct object to use as `this`. You can pass that object as the second parameter to your `map`. Like this:

```
this.props.products.map(mapProductCards, this);
```

You might find the documentation for [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)over at [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) interesting:

> ```
> var new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue, index, array) {
>     // Return element for new_array
> }[, thisArg])
> ```
>
> **thisArg:** Optional. Value to use as this when executing callback.

Comment: sorry, but it doesn't help. BTW I'm using "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties" plugin, that makes autobinding for me. But anyway I changed this to that like you say but still an error. Here's a screenshot of an error http://imgur.com/DJneu5n .

Comment: @TarasYaremkiv okay. On which line are you getting the error? Is it still the same place? That error means that `this` doesn't have a `props` property, so it should be related.

Comment: I'm getting an error from proptypes.   "171:18  error  'addItemToCart' PropType is defined but prop is never used  react/no-unused-prop-types". Sorry it's not the same error

Comment: Console log your `this` object at the start of your `mapProductCards` function, before the `return`, and post the output here.

Comment: it prints me undefined in console. Actually if you haven't seen - here's a link to the whole container code https://gist.github.com/Y-Taras/be0777006e925a9d80e367221a481caf

Comment: okay, this should work then: change your `map` to this: `.map(mapProductCards, this)`. Keep the console output. Is it still undefined?

Comment: Well now no errors, but addItemToCart(elem.id) still isn't working as expected. I mean it got to add ids to the redux store but it doesn't (

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue and the problem was when i debugged my code ,local this ie this object of the function was giving undefined object.you need to instantiate this object of the function **addItemToCart** because when you click the button it will give you an error on console saying

Your method addItemToCart is undefined
 to overcome this you need to define local this as

```
      renderProductsList() {
      var localThis= this;
}
```

and then call your method as

```
onClick={() => localThis.props.addItemToCart(elem.id)}
```

If you are using a function inside a loop say map then you need to do

```
this.state.map(function(){


},**this**)
```

to preserve this

Comment: sorry, but it doesn't help. BTW I'm using "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties" plugin, that makes autobinding for me. Here's a screenshot of an error http://imgur.com/DJneu5n .

Comment: not able to open your image.restricted in office.can you please tell the error?

Comment: can you just check if console.log(this) insode your function renderProductsList is giving undefined or not?

Comment: error is the same actually. PropType is defined but prop is never used  react/no-unused-prop-types,

Comment: this.addItemToCart(elem.id) should work fine.Why are you using props while calling a function?

Comment: it won't work because it is from redux. These functions are in different scopes